# How to colorize text in emacs?

Tags: emacs, colors

I want to view (and/or edit) colorized text in emacs, such as is output by `ls -l --color=always`, `tree...`, or whatever.

The text I refer to exists in a file. When I open that file in emacs, I want to be able to see it colorized, or toggle it to show ANSI (SGR) escape sequences.

`ansi-color.el` *seems* be be what I need, but I haven't been able to get it to do any colorizing of the ANSi escape **sequences**, but I do see blue-bold for individual **contol bytes** (eg. `^A` and `^[`)... I'm not sure if that is a feature of `ansi-color`, but I think it is.

According to the [ansi-color.el comments](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ansi-color.el), it can work with strings and regions, but even that doesn't seem to work.. For example the function `ansi-color-apply-on-region` is not recognized by `M-x`. It says, "No match"

I've added `(require 'ansi-color)` to my *.emacs* file and even `(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)`. I get no error or warning when emacs starts, so I'm stuck.

How can I get the standard functions to work, and can it be made to automatically apply when opening a file whose name is suffixed with `.col`?

Comment: https://github.com/atomontage/xterm-color

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the piece you're missing is the `interactive` form.  It's how Emacs distinguishes between a function designed to be called by other functions, and a function designed to be called directly by the user.  See the Emacs Lisp Intro [node](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/Interactive.html#Interactive)

Now if you read the definition of `ansi-color-apply-on-region`, you'll see that it's not designed for interactive use.  "ansi-color" is designed to filter comint output.  However it's easy to make an interactive wrapper for it.

```
(defun ansi-color-apply-on-region-int (beg end)
  "interactive version of func"
  (interactive "r")
  (ansi-color-apply-on-region beg end))
```

The next bit is you want to turn on ansi colors for the .col extension.  You can add a hook function to whatever major-mode you want use to edit those files.  The function would be run whenever you turn on the major-mode, so you will have to add a check for the proper file suffix.

Alternatively you can hack a quick derived mode based on "fundamental" mode.

```
(define-derived-mode fundamental-ansi-mode fundamental-mode "fundamental ansi"
  "Fundamental mode that understands ansi colors."
  (require 'ansi-color)
  (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max)))
```

and associate it with that extension.

```
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (cons '("\\.col\\'" . fundamental-ansi-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

Comment: Fantastic.. as if by magic!  Well explained, and your [Make a Function Interactive](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/Interactive.html#Interactive) link helped a lot.  I'm *starting* to see the general structure of Emacs.  Thanks...

Comment: I wonder what I am doing wrong. I added all text you have above in my .emacs file but the text that I highlight doesn't seems to get colored after invoking ansi-color-apply-on-region-int.

Comment: How can I apply it for the full buffer?

Answer (score 7):

The following solution allow to read (and not save) files containing ANSI color sequences. The filenames must have a `.txt` extension.

Put the library [tty-format](ftp://download.tuxfamily.org/user42/tty-format.el) in `~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/`, then add these lines to your `~/.emacs` init file.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/")              
(require 'tty-format)
(add-hook 'find-file-hooks 'tty-format-guess)
```

Comment: This is a useful option too. It utilizes `ansi-color` and takes it one step further to, as your link says, *"...The aim of tty-format.el is just to make *such files* viewable."* .. "*such files*" being those containing *ANSI SGR escape sequences and backspacing*.. Thanks..

Comment: For what it's worth.. This method vs the fully editable version as posted by *event_jr* has faster (~25%) **continuous** paging speed with significanlty better (much! better) refresh frequency.. The test file had 45,000 lines. For the editable version the screen refresh ground to halt at about 75% of the way through the file, but the scroll bar was still scrolling.. I suspect this is because of some overhead of some point/mark undo buffer in the editable version...  Both methods have their advantages... (by *"continuous"*, I mean keeping the Page Up/Down key pressed continuously)

Comment: PS.. *tty-format* pages as smoothly and as fast as *less* does in the terminal (the times were within a second or two of each other; approx. 50 seconds from top-botton, and bottom-top).

Comment: I wasn't aware of `tty-format`.  It seems to be superior to my wrapper function or 3 line derived-mode.  :)  Emacs has a hard time dealing with a lot of overlays, which is how ansi-color does the colorization.  There is opportunity for further optimization here, because we don't need to colorize the whole buffer, just the part being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much @enzotib for your solution !

Just as an addition to your solution, here is a way to make it explicitly callable by the user:

```
;; M-x display-ansi-colors to explicitly decode ANSI color escape sequences                                                                                                                                        
(defun display-ansi-colors ()
  (interactive)
  (format-decode-buffer 'ansi-colors))
```

and automatic for files other than just *.txt or README:

```
;; decode ANSI color escape sequences for .log files                                                                                                                                                               
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.log\\'" . display-ansi-colors))
```

This way you can replace your escape sequences with colors without altering the original file, unlike solutions using `ansi-color-apply-on-region`.